# SSH to EC2: Operation timed out. Maybe a resources misconfiguration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I manually configured my network. The instance identified with `'i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'` is attached to the NIC `'eni-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'`, attached to the subnet `'subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'`, routed to the internet via `'igw-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'`  through the `'rtb-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'`.

The instance is attached a Security Group, and that group allows Inbound Connections origined at `0.0.0.0/0` on TCP, port 22. Also, I'm allowed to use a keypair, which I have the private key for.

However, I'm completely unable to do a simple SSH handshaking. The response on my side is "Operation timed out".

Do you think there is something I'm missing?

EDIT: Here's the debug response

```
➜ ssh -vv ec2-user@18.223.62.46 

OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/pandres95/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 18.223.62.46 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 18.223.62.46 [18.223.62.46] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 18.223.62.46 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 18.223.62.46 port 22: Operation timed out
```

Comment: Did you start the instance?

Comment: share `ssh -vv <ip>` output.

Comment: I did @MichaelHampton.

Comment: Here's the output @asktyagi

Comment: Looks like security policy issue, can you test ssh port reachability from your machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have only **one ENI** on the instance or two? If you have two you may run into problems with routing - detach one and see if it helps.

If you only have one ENI and you really have the *security group* open to `0.0.0.0/0` on `tcp/22` and if your *VPC networking* is all set as you described then the last remaining reason is a **host-based firewall** blocking the inbound traffic.

For start run `iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT; iptables -X` and try `ssh` again.

Oh, wait, you can't login to it to fix the iptables, right? You can use *SSM Session* for out of bounds access, provided your instance has the SSM agent running. Amazon Linux 2 usually starts SSM agent automatically but you may have to add some permissions to the instance IAM Role - see **[Using SSM Session Manager for interactive instance access](https://aws.nz/best-practice/ssm-session-manager/)** and **[SSM Sessions the easy way](https://aws.nz/projects/ssm-session/)**. You may not even need the SSH fixed after you get SSM Session running after all.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you’ve got a **Public or Elastic IP** attached to your instance.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I made sure there was. I was actually trying to SSH using that IP from my machine. 
Also, tried associating an Elastic IP, but didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Your subnet will have a Network Access Control List (NACL).

If the subnet is not the default subnet for the VPC, it will have a NACL that blocks all traffic. You will have to permit TCP 22 ingress and global egress in that NACL.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's obvious but make sure it is the correct "user" of the EC2, for example:
ssh -i xxx-xxx-xxx.pem **some-ec2-user**@ec2-1-15-333-999.compute-9.amazonaws.com

Comment: A wrong username does not result in a timeout.